# visual studio code golang package import problem

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

could someone enlighten me on how to get simple import statements in vsc to work for an example main.go file I borrowed from somewhere? The following observations apply:

1. go version go1.17.2 windows/amd64;
2. I can get this program to run (using modules) without any problems;
3. The imports in my main program are for fyne like e.g. "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app" etc.;
4. $GOROOT points to something like C:\Program files\Go.. ;
5. $GOPATH points to C:\Users\xyz\go.... ;
6. My current source code is located under $GOPATH\src... but can be moved somewhere else if
   needed;
7. In my source subdirectory there is a main.go and I added a module file as follows:
   go mod init main & go mod tidy
   this results in the following output : `go: finding module for package fyne.io/fyne/v2/app go: finding module for package fyne.io/fyne/v2 go: finding module for package fyne.io/fyne/v2/container go: finding module for package fyne.io/fyne/v2/canvas go: found fyne.io/fyne/v2 in fyne.io/fyne/v2 v2.1.2 go: found fyne.io/fyne/v2/app in fyne.io/fyne/v2 v2.1.2 go: found fyne.io/fyne/v2/canvas in fyne.io/fyne/v2 v2.1.2 go: found fyne.io/fyne/v2/container in fyne.io/fyne/v2 v2.1.2`

So it seems that everything thats needed is there and I can subsequently run the program.

8. However when displaying my main.go source in vsc (1.63.0) it complains about not being able to find(import) any of the required fyne packages/imports. It lists that it looks in the \src subdirectories of both $GOROOT and $GOPATH but can't find anything. This is actually correct because there is nothing there. The closest I can find are fyne packages located under
   C:\Users\xyz\go\pkg\mod\fyne.io\fyne...

Looked at all kinds of documentation but have no clue of whats exactly the problem and how to solve this.

Thanks in advance
Peter

Comment: Can you share your project directory structure, i.e. what folder did you open from the vscode, does the root folder contain your go.mod file? Info in https://github.com/golang/vscode-go#setting-up-your-workspace may be helpful.

note: GOPATH is no longer very relevant in recent versions of Go.

Answer (score 0):

Your dependencies should be located in the right place, i.e. where the build tool, in this case vsc is expecting them. So move them there, and set your `GOPATH` correctly as explained here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-setup-golang-with-vscode/